# What is the correct differential equation for logistic growth?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logistic-regression

OK so my textbook claims that the correct differential equation for a logistic growth scenario is

y'=ky(1-(y/carry capacity))

However, we were given a handout which claims that it should be

y'=ky(carrying capacity-y)

Of course they both integrate into two completely different equations, but which SHOULD be used when I am given a logistic growth scenario type of question?

Comment: Are you sure that $k$ is the same in both...?

Comment: They're the same, just for different $k$s

Comment: the K should be same i believe, so yeah.

Comment: so ur saying that the K on the handout is actually "K" = k(carrying capacity)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOL thanks for the hints, apparently the "k" in the two equations are not the "same" because the the K on the handout is actually = (k of textbook)(carrying capacity)